# how to get metrics on my k8s api/master nodes

Tags: prometheus, minikube

I am using minikube to learn more about kubernetes and was wondering how i could build something that would track the metrics of my master/api nodes. Do I need to build an application that tracks it through prometheus?

I have setup minikube to use the docker driver so is this something I would do in a Dockerfile?

Any direction you can give would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minikube has a default addon to do exactly what I think you are wanting. To enable this addon you can simply run:

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```